# Heavy workload in ec2 ubuntu cause ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer

Tags: 14.04, amazon-ec2, aws

I am recently experiencing problem with `t2.micro` with unlimited enabled such that the instance runs into `ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer` when cpu usage averages 70%

I am not exactly sure why this happens, can someone give me a hint?